# Good site but too many answers also some confusing answers

Tags: discussion

Look at this:

[Difference between require, include and require_once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418473/when-should-i-use-require-once-vs-include)

There are  many answers  and counter questions I some times feel I'm reading someone else's chat messages.

The creators of this site have great intentions but some users have only wrong intentions –just increase some reputation–yes I meant it. I have seen so many answers here which are just plain rip offs of someone else's answers in the same thread.

Unless you  guys do something like highlighting the answers with the most upvotes or something (I saw the tick, but noobs don't even notice it, I'm afraid).

Just hoping this site won't become uninteresting for new users.

Comment: Are you sorting answers correctly?  If you sort by votes, the highest-voted answer will rise to the top.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Stack Exchange works, in part, based on the idea of [crowdsourcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowdsourcing): you ask a question of a large, diverse population that provides you with a number of individual answers, and ostensibly the responses will converge on an answer that solves the problem you have.

To that end, it's essential Stack Exchange provides the opportunity for (mostly) anyone to answer a question at any time: there's no way to know beforehand whether the first answer is correct or whether some guy, 4 years from now, just happens upon the question and provides the best answer ever.

The end result is that questions will generally have multiple answers: that's good for everyone, as bad or non-optimal answers get replaced with better ones over time. The community converges on the best possible answer by voting: the answers the community and the asker generally consider to be correct *right now* will be at the top.<sup>1</sup>

If you're in a hurry or confused and did nothing but look at the top answer you're very likely going to be fine. If the top answer is wrong or doesn't help, that's what the other answers are for: if they didn't exist, there'd be no alternative to an answer that's wrong but happened to get there first.

There may be some merit to making the top answer more prominent, but it's already pretty prominent by virtue of being first (and very likely above the fold).

<sup>Note 1: unless the question asker accepts his or her own answer, due to conflict of interest</sup>

Comment: Hi...it helps if you are an experienced user of the site...but as newbies ..as you might be aware  are always in the look out for more explanations (may be hungry for more info)...gets confused..and whats the point in having so many answers ,Storin too much unnecessary data in the server , (i don't know if its going to slow down the site )

Comment: @jathin I assure you, having multiple answers on a question does not significantly slow down the site. Again, you don't need to look at any of those extra answers if you don't want to: the one vetted by the community and the asker is always at the top. Stack Exchange is constantly updated and the answers provided are constantly vetted by the community: if questions locked after getting one answer, there'd be no way to provide a better answer if the first one sucked.

Comment: Hi                                                                   Mine was just a suggestion . I didn't say you must limit the answers. By this "Unless you guys do something like highlighting the answers with the most up votes or something ", I actually meant some highlighting of background, see some new users don't even notice the tick mark(the inactive white one--until the answer is accepted ) Also the down voted answers are still visible i think(not sure).if you make it disappear say after 10 or 15 downvotes ,it'd be less annoying. Your answer is correct in a sense.

Comment: @jathin After a total about three or four downvotes, it will turn grey. Also, unless you changed it, the order is: 1.) The one with a bounty (if there is one), 2.) Accepted answer (again, if there is one), and 3.) the rest of the answers, sorted from the highest score to the lowest. We already do what you're trying to say in a way.